# Add 1 to column names that ends in integer r

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

My problem is quite straightforward, I have a dataframe with many columns, some of them start with `q03b_`, like this:

```
ID  ...  q03b_0 q03b_1 q03b_2 ... q03b_14
 1  ...    a      b      c           m
```

But I need to change the column names to `q03b_other_1`, `q03b_other_2`, `q03b_other_3`, etc (counting from 1 instead of 0). I managed to select the columns with `rename_at` and add the "other" to the column names, like this:

```
df  %>% 
  rename_at(vars(matches('q03b_')), list(~ str_replace(., "b_(\\d+)", "_other_\\1")))
```

Which brings a dataframe like this:

```
ID  ...  q03_other_0 q03_other_1 q03_other_2 ... q03_other_14
 1  ...    a               b          c               m
```

But I'm struggling to get to the final stage, which would be this:

```
ID  ...  q03_other_1 q03_other_2 q03_other_3 ... q03_other_15
 1  ...    a                b           c                m
```

I guess I need to use a combination of `as.numeric` and `as.character`, but because of tidy evaluation I'm struggling to find a way to make this work. Any ideas?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `gsubfn`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(gsubfn)

df %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches('q03b_')), 
            list(~ gsubfn("b_\\d+$", 
                          ~ paste0("_other_", 
                                   parse_number(x) + 1), 
                          .)))
```

**Output**

```
  q03_other_1 q03_other_2 q03_other_3
1           a           b           c
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! Forgot in the question that I needed to drop the b from the name. I did this to fix it:

`df %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches('q03b_')), list(~ gsubfn::gsubfn("\\d+$", ~ paste("other", as.numeric(x) + 1, sep = "_"), .) %>% str_replace('b', '')))` Would you say it's the best way? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear. I might use `parse_number` from `readr` or alternative to `as.numeric`, then you can add "b_" in the pattern as well...let me know if this works for you...(I used to use `extract_numeric` from `tidyr`)...

Comment: See edited answer and let me know if this works for you...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you *have* to get the number from the original column names, add +1 to it to create new columns.

This works without doing that -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rename_with(~paste0('q03_other_', seq_along(.)), starts_with('q03b_'))

#  ID q03_other_1 q03_other_2 q03_other_3
#1  1           a           b           c
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1, q03b_0 = 'a', q03b_1 = 'b', q03b_2 = 'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way using `sprintf`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  select(-ID) %>% 
  rename_with(~str_replace(., "[0-9]+$", sprintf("%.0f", 1:length(colnames(df))))) %>% 
  rename_with(~str_replace(., "b", "")) %>% 
  bind_cols(ID=df$ID)
```

```
  q03_other_1 q03_other_2 q03_other_3 ID
1           a           b           c  1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_replace(., "b_\\d+$", function(x)
     str_c('_other_', readr::parse_number(x) + 1)) , starts_with('q03b_'))
  ID q03_other_1 q03_other_2 q03_other_3
1  1           a           b           c
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1L, q03b_0 = "a", q03b_1 = "b", q03b_2 = "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                ID = c(1L),
            q03b_0 = c("a"),
            q03b_1 = c("b"),
            q03b_2 = c("c")
      )

names(df)[-1] <- names(df)[-1] %>% 
  str_remove("_.*") %>% 
  paste0("_other_",1:length(.))

df
#>   ID q03b_other_1 q03b_other_2 q03b_other_3
#> 1  1            a            b            c
```

**EDIT:** A more general solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                ID = c(1L),
            q03b_0 = c("a"),
            q03b_1 = c("b"),
            q03b_2 = c("c")
      )

names(df)[str_detect(names(df), "^q03b_")] %<>% 
  str_split("_") %>% 
  map_chr(~ paste0(.x[1], "_other_", 1+as.numeric(.x[2])))

df 
#>   ID q03b_other_1 q03b_other_2 q03b_other_3
#> 1  1            a            b            c
```

Comment: In practice my dataframe has 27 columns, so this wouldn't work. I think using names indexes might be a little unreadable and prone to errors too. Thanks anyways

Comment: That is unclear why that would not work because you have 27 columns, @JuanC.

Comment: Because it presumes the columns I want to change are all after the first one

Comment: I guess, @JuanC,  you were looking for something like my second solution:

Comment: Now, my edited solution works as you want, @JuanC.